# Analytics API v4 Invalid json payload error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-analytics-api, google-sheets-api

I am writing Google apps script in Google spreadsheet code editor. I want pull some data from Google Analytics that must using GA API v4. I know there is build in support for Analytics API in Google apps script but only v3 version.

So I follow this guide [Google Apps Script - External API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external#making_requests_to_services_with_oauth) and using this library [googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2) to do oauth2.

I am sure I have enabled Analytics V4 API in API console and get the right client ID and secret. After auth2 I wrote code to access data

```
  var payload = {'reportRequests' : [
    {
      'metrics' : [{'expression':'ga:users'}],
      'viewId' : 'xxxxxxxx',
      'dateRages' : [{'startDate':'2016-10-01','endDate':'2016-10-10'}]
    }
  ]};

  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'headers': {
       'contentType': 'application/json',
       'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
     },
    'payload' : payload,
    'muteHttpExceptions':true
   };

  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet", options);
  Logger.log(resp.getContentText());
```

Then I got a error http response

```
[16-10-30 21:25:51:325 PDT] {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"reportRequests\": Cannot bind query parameter. 'reportRequests' is a message type. Parameters can only be bound to primitive types.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"reportRequests\": Cannot bind query parameter. 'reportRequests' is a message type. Parameters can only be bound to primitive types."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? and what does the error message mean?

Thank you!

Comment: Make sure you also turn on or enable the Analytics API in the Advance Google Services in the Script editor that you are using. *Resource* -> *Advance Google Services* -> *Turn on Analytics API*. Another thing that I think can help you is by reading this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/authorization).

Comment: it has been enabled in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Two potential issues:

1. The error states `INVALID_ARGUMENT`. Your payload contains `dateRages`, which should be `dateRanges`, otherwise it will not be recognised as a valid request owing to the typo.
2. See this [answer regarding passing JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486460/how-to-link-google-sheets-and-docusign-api-with-google-scripts/40665693#40665693): If you wish to pass data of Content-Type `application/json` then you need to provide a string to the `payload` parameter, not a JS Object.

   Instead of:

   ```
   // JS Object, by default will be encoded as formdata (not desired)
   'payload' : payload
   ```

   Use:

   ```
   // Convert JS Object to JSON string
   'payload' : JSON.stringify(payload)
   ```

Hope this helps