# How to link Google Sheets and Docusign API with Google Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, docusignapi, google-sheets-api

I am trying to automatically send an envelope with Docusign when a Google form is submitted. I have written the following code in the Google Script Editor

```
// When Form Gets submitted

function onFormSubmit(e) {

//Get information from form and set our variables 

  var full_name = e.values[2];
  var email_address = e.values[3];

// Send the email

  var subject = "TEST trigger";
  var body    = "Thank you for testing" + full_name + "";

  MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, 
                    subject, 
                    body); 

   var url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restApi/v2/accounts/<accountname>/envelopes";

   var payload =
   {
  "emailSubject": "Please sign stuff",
  "emailBlurb": "TesttextTesttextTesttextTesttextTesttext",
  "templateId": "7078020e-49a0-42c6-b77d-368211d4a666",
   "templateRoles": [
    {
      "roleName": "client",
      "name": full_name,
      "email": email_address
    },
    {
      "roleName": "name",
      "name": "name",
      "email": "emailaddress"
    },
    {
      "roleName": "name2",
      "name": "name2",
      "email": "emailaddress2"
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent"
   }

   var options =
   {
     "contentType": "application/json",
     "method" : "post",
     "headers": 
     {
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication": "{\"Username\":\"<username>\",\"Password\":\"<pw>\",\"IntegratorKey\":\"<integratorkey>"}"
  },
     "payload" : payload
   };

   UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
 }
```

I get the following error message and it seems there is something wrong with the formatting:

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net:7802/restApi/v2/accounts/<accountid>/envelopes

TraceToken: 0304eb5f-1188-4880-a22c-861839f4e8d9
Timestamp: 2016-10-25T09:40:49.0423980Z

Content-Length: 187
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: Keep-alive
Host: demo.docusign.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0(compatible; Google-Apps-Script)
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"<email>","Password":"[omitted]","IntegratorKey":"[omitted]"}
X-BROKER-EVENT-ID: AHI413WWv-VgeLRQbOpMQH-Y6J-93aHL4h5phAVpXeXUqK8RsYof90Eu68CI-LkC1Ef4FM8Hac-1
X-Forwarded-For: 107.178.192.41
X-SecurityProtocol-Version: TLSv1.2
X-SecurityProtocol-CipherSuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Accept: application/json

emailBlurb=TesttextTesttextTesttextTesttextTesttext&templateRoles=%5BLjava.lang.Object;@3449f174&templateId=7078020e-49a0-42c6-b77d-368211d4a666&emailSubject=Please+sign+stuff&status=sent
400 BadRequest
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
  "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_BODY",
  "message": "The request body is missing or improperly formatted. Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: e. Path '', line 0, position 0."
}
```

Any help on how to proceed would be great.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that you're specifying that you are submitting data in JSON format, and the server is presumably expecting that but in fact your data is not in that format.

By default, when encountering a JavaScript object as an argument to the `payload` option, as you are providing, Apps Script with encode it as a form data.

Instead of specifying:

```
// Payload is a JS object and will be encoded as formdata by default
"payload" : payload
```

You need to specify:

```
// Payload is now a JSON representation of the payload variable.
"payload" : JSON.stringify(payload)
```

This should help.